Blender x Maui for UI elements like animated logo, background, etc
I'm a 3d artist using exclusively Blender, and also a dev. I'm currently working on a .Net MAUI project.
I would like to implement UI animations in my project, made with Blender.
Webp animations is not supported, and I converted png animations to Lottie files but I had issues with transparency.
I tried webview components for webp animations, but it doesn't look great (for example, when I get back to a page, the webview component started black for a millisecond, and play the webp animation. Since I used it for an animated logo, I couldn't use the alpha channel).
Any advice to implement animated elements like logo, or background, made in Blender, in a .Net MAUI project?
